# Network interface binding appears to only work as root

Tags: linux, networking

I have a CentOS 7 server with two network interfaces. One points to our LAN (ens32) and the other to our DMZ (ens33).

While the LAN interface works fine, I noticed that it seems like the traffic will only traverse the DMZ interface if logged in as root, and I'm unsure what this means or if it has any net effect on other issues that I'm experiencing.

For example, if I run:

```
curl --interface ens32 ipecho.net/plain
```

as a non-root user, I'll get the public IP for that interface.

If I run:

```
curl --interface ens33 ipecho.net/plain
```

as a non-root user, the command appears to stall and I'll be forced to kill the process.

If I run the previous command as root, I'll get the expected output which is the public IP for that interface.

Can anyone explain what might be going on here?

Comment: Do you have a host firewall (e.g., iptables) configured? If so, that'd be the place I'd start. E.g., `owner` match...

Comment: @derobert firewalld is running on the system, but this happens even when I disable the daemon.

Comment: I just ran the same command from above with the -v flag for verbose output from curl and this is what I got:

    * About to connect() to ipecho.net port 80 (#0)
    *   Trying 146.255.36.1...
    * Local Interface ens33 is ip 172.16.5.200 using address family 2
    * SO_BINDTODEVICE ens33 failed with errno 1: Operation not permitted; will do regular bind
    * Local port: 0

Comment: [edit] those details in to your question — then it's much easier to use code formatting to make them readable..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it can be seen in the official `curl` page, to specify/bind to a specific interface, there is a need to either have CAP_NET_RAW or to run as `root`.

Hence thus `root` being able to do the binding/routing, and it not working with a regular user for you.

When a regular user is using `curl`, without it being no permitted to use the `--interface` option, the default routing rules of the server will apply to that operation instead.

From the curl official page [curl.1 the man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --interface
>
> Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can enter
>   interface name, IP address or host name. An example could look like:
>
> curl --interface eth0:1 https://www.example.com/
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
>
> **On Linux it can be used to specify a VRF, but the binary needs to
>   either have CAP_NET_RAW or to be ran as root.**
>
> More information about
>   Linux VRF: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt